# mySQL subquery with limits error

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I have two section with games and I have a problem. When is game in the first section I don't want show her again in the Second section. 
For show games in First Section I'm using:

```
SELECT *,platform.platformName FROM games 
JOIN platform ON(platform.PlatformID=games.GamePlatform) 
WHERE GameDate <= NOW() AND GameSlide = 0 
GROUP BY GameName 
HAVING 1 
ORDER BY `games`.`GameDate` DESC LIMIT 8
```

For show Games in Second Section:

```
SELECT *,platform.platformName 
FROM games 
JOIN platform ON(platform.PlatformID=games.GamePlatform) 
WHERE platform.PlatformID = 2 AND GameSlide = 0 
GROUP BY GameName 
HAVING 1 
order by rand(dayofyear(CURRENT_DATE)) 
LIMIT 8
```

I tried to make subquery like this:

```
SELECT *,platform.platformName 
FROM games 
JOIN platform ON(platform.PlatformID=games.GamePlatform) 
WHERE games.GameID 
NOT IN(
       SELECT GameID 
       FROM games 
       WHERE GameDate <= NOW() AND GameSlide = 0 
       GROUP BY GameName 
       HAVING 1 
       ORDER BY `games`.`GameDate` DESC LIMIT 8
      ) AND platform.PlatformID = 2 AND GameSlide = 0 
GROUP BY GameName 
HAVING 1 
order by rand(dayofyear(CURRENT_DATE)) LIMIT 8
```

But MySQL call error : `#1235 - This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Can you help me please? 
I'm sorry for my English. I tried my best.

Comment: MySQL or MariaDB? See [MySQL::C.4 Restrictions on Subqueries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-restrictions.html) or 
[MariaDB::Subquery Limitations](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/subquery-limitations/)

Comment: Even if this did work, the `ORDER BY GameDate DESC LIMIT 8'` would not necessarily give you the same 8 records in the sub query as it did in the section 1 query (assuming GameDate is not unique). Also I'm confused what the `HAVING 1` is for. Might be helpful to see some sample records.

Comment: I have many games with same name and same release date 
the only difference is in the platform. For example: GTA V for PS4, Xbox and PC and I want to show only one from them, so I used HAVING 1 on GamesName. 
I need use `Limid 8` and `order by GameDate Desc` in subqury  because when I delete `LIMIT 8` Subquery return all games so result doesn't show anything and when I delete the `ORDER BY GameDate DEST` It doesn't returns the lasteted games. If you want I can send you some screeshots with databese and website how it's looks and how I mean it.:)

Comment: Here is some screeshots: http://prnt.sc/dinrtz (website ) 
                                          http://prnt.sc/dinsh3 (Tables wchich I'm using )

Answer (score 0):

I already done it. I make a new View with the select.

```
CREATE VIEW Novinky AS SELECT games.GameID FROM games WHERE games.GameDate <= NOW() AND games.GameSlide = 0 GROUP BY games.GameName HAVING 1 ORDER BY `games`.`GameDate` DESC LIMIT 8
```

And then use NOT IN with SELECT from View:

```
SELECT *,platform.platformName FROM games JOIN platform ON(platform.PlatformID=games.GamePlatform) WHERE GameID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM novinky) AND platform.PlatformID = 2 AND GameSlide = 0 GROUP BY GameName HAVING 1 order by rand(dayofyear(CURRENT_DATE)) LIMIT 8
```

Comment: I suspect that there's a more efficient solution, but well done.